# Is it possible to use Portable Bitmap Image in TBitmap Component in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to use Portable Bitmap Image(pbm) in TBitmap Component in Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33) supports the PBM format.

Comment: Ahh, Mike Lischke really is a superstar